# why OEM allow to connect system as normal and sys dont?

Tags: oracle

In OEM I can connect with system as normal but with sys cant connect as normal. Why is that?

Comment: That has nothing to do with OEM - you wouldn't be able to connect through SQLPlus with sys "as normal" either

Comment: @luis Suarez Have you ever tried to login as normal user with sys account from sqlplus ?.If you try it gives the error                                                   ERROR:
"ORA-28009: connection as SYS should be as SYSDBA or SYSOPER"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this is how it was designed.

[7.3.2 SYSDBA and SYSOPER System Privileges](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/admqs/administering-user-accounts-and-security.html#GUID-2033E766-8FE6-4FBA-97E0-2607B083FA2C)

> The SYS user is automatically granted the SYSDBA privilege upon
>   installation. **When you log in as user SYS, you must connect to the
>   database as SYSDBA or SYSOPER**.